# Мануалы по для обучения Laravel 5 +

Tags: php, laravel

Есть опыт работы с laravel. Но иногда сталкиваюсь с новыми возможностями фреймворка. Хочется закрыть пробелы в познаниях. 
Мануалы которыми я руководствуюсь в данный момент это [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/) и [официальная документация](https://laravel.com/docs/master). Какие еще есть источники либо хорошие примеры использования, или как узнать о всех возможностях различных классов?

Comment: а на английском устроит ?? и в youtube вроде есть чуток видео https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Laravel+5+%2B

Comment: @LenovoID Спасибо, как-то не задумался за  youtube. Что-то на вроде книги бы найти)

Comment: На сайте издательства O'Reilly можно посмотреть, например, http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781785283017.do